# Class influences other class behavior in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, type-traits

I have the following code to detect if a type `T` has a function with a specific return type and parameters parameters (simplified version generated by some more complex macros):

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

namespace has_private
{
    template <typename...>
    using void_t = void;

    template <typename T>
    struct identity
    {
        using type = T;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct add_const
    {
        using type = const T;
    };
}  // namespace has_private

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_bytes : std::false_type
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0, "Incomplete type");
};

template <typename T>
struct has_bytes<
    T,
    has_private::void_t<decltype(std::declval<typename has_private::add_const<T&>::type>().bytes())>>
    : std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<typename has_private::add_const<T&>::type>().bytes()), size_t>
{
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_capacity : std::false_type
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0, "Incomplete type");
};

template <typename T>
struct has_capacity<
    T,
    has_private::void_t<decltype(std::declval<typename has_private::add_const<T&>::type>().capacity())>>
    : std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<typename has_private::add_const<T&>::type>().capacity()), size_t>
{
};

static_assert(has_capacity<std::vector<int>>::value, "should have");
static_assert(has_capacity<std::complex<int>>::value == false, "shouldn't have");
```

This code compiles fine with VS2019, GCC 7+, clang 7+ but with VS2015 it doesn't compile. If I remove the `has_bytes` or if I move `has_bytes` after `has_capacity` the code compiles with VS2015. By the looks of it this seems to be a compiler bug.

Is this a compiler bug? If yes, do you know any workarounds this bug?

I can't just move the `has_bytes` after `has_capacity` because these trait classes are generated using macros from multiple places and their behavior must be reliable.

EDIT:
This is the complete error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>source\repos\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(51): error C2338: should have
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

EDIT: I'm using latest version of VS2019 with `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)` Toolchain. I'm not exactly sure how to check the version in this case

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: don't you already know the workaaround? "if I move has_bytes after has_capacity the code compiles with VS2015. " ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 consoleapplication1.cpp(51): error C2338: should have

Comment: the error message must be more than that (or VS is much crappier than I want to believe). Please include the complete error message in the quesiton

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is not a reliable workaround as the code is generated from more complex macros that are everywhere in the code. I can't rely on the definition order

Comment: we can only consider boundary conditions that are mentioned explicitly in your question. I mean what other constraints are there due to the macros? We cannot know

Comment: [Edit] your question and put the complete error log _there_ as text ans not as a picture.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've posted the full build log - sorry for missing that, I though it's obvious that the error is generated by the ```static_assert```

Comment: Just to cover all the bases: What version of VS2015 are you using? Did you try to update it? In case it was compiler defect, it might have been fixed.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug to me. Can't you drop VS2015 which is getting somewhat old.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Unfortunately it's not my decisions and I can't upgrade the compiler

Comment: This looks like a compiler error. I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).